# Why closure - How easy is it for banned cheaters in CS:GO to sidestep their ban?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Arqade post: [How easy is it for banned cheaters in CS:GO to sidestep their ban?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351137/how-easy-is-it-for-banned-cheaters-in-csgo-to-sidestep-their-ban)

1. I don't see how [my post is a "double post"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351139/how-effectively-are-cheaters-on-counter-strike-global-offensive-banned?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment493807_351139), when it can be clearly distinguished from my other question.
2. I'm a shade dismayed by all the downvotes. Why? I'm trying to play the game without cheating and would like some assurance against cheating, but I appear to have been misinterpreted to be asking how to cheat. If cheating isn't banned effectively, then how can I play?

Comment: "_If cheating isn't banned effectively, then how can I play?_"  You can basically only play single player games, in that case.  When it comes to cheating in video games, you will find people who are suspicious about cheating even at the professional levels where they have extra layers of cheat prevention.  I would suggest doing what every other legitimate player does, live with the reality that some people cheat in video games and there's no perfect way to prevent it.  Personally, I always try to assume it's skill and work backwards from there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your second question was properly closed as duplicate of your first question.  While the wording is different, the end effect of that difference is that the second question isn't even a question at all.  If there actually was a question there, it would have largely been the same as the first question, and therefore a duplicate.
2. Users are not obligated to explain their reasons for downvoting a question, but in this case, I think it's fairly safe to say that it's because  the question *looked* like it was asking how to circumvent anti-cheating mechanisms.  That's a big no-no within this community.  The reason the second question got more downvotes is because it's a duplicate question before the first was even closed.  That's really bad within our community, as it shows that you don't want to follow the rules and standards for our community.  I mean, it probably would have been just as downvoted if you had asked after the first question was closed, but doing so before shows a kind of arrogance that's not welcome here.

But to sum up, if you don't want to cheat, then don't cheat!  Cheating, especially on a game like CS:GO is an active decision.  If you do want to cheat, then you're not welcome here.

Comment: "if you don't want to cheat, then don't cheat!" I'm asking about others who cheat? If the answer is that there are many and they aren't banned, then I'm not playing CS:GO.

Comment: @PostmodernistAntinatalist cheaters are being banned all the time, just not instantly and not all of them. We don't know how many cheaters are out there. And we don't know how many of them are just good players and still accused of cheating or how many cheaters get away, because they cover it up pretty good... questions like that are not answerable.

Comment: @PostmodernistAntinatalist You're asking about how to get around cheats. Even if you're only asking because you're curious and have no intention of using the info to cheat, the fact is that once answered, the info is now publicly available and anyone who *does* want to cheat can follow those instructions. That's why the question was downvoted and closed.